# Is the Poset of Graphs Automorphism-free?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, posets, graph-reconstruction

For $n\geq 5$, let $\mathcal {P}_n$ be the set of all isomorphism classes of graphs with n vertices. Give this set the poset structure given by $G \le H$ if and only if $G$ is a subgraph of $H$.

> Is it true that $\mathcal {P}_n$ has no nontrivial automorphisms?

**Remarks:**

This follows if one can recognize a graph from the set of isomorphism classes of its edge-deleted subgraphs. However, since recognizing a graph from the set of isomorphism classes of its edge-deleted subgraphs is stronger than edge reconstruction, I'm wondering if there is an alternative way of proving this.

Comment: Maybe it is useful to add that $\cal P_4$ has a nontrivial automorphism. Did you ckeck for higher values, e.g. using the tables from http://www.maths.uq.edu.au/~pa/research/posets4to8.html?

Comment: $\mathcal P_5$ can pretty easily be checked by hand. As for anything larger, I'm not sure.

Comment: Of course there is in fact no need to check, as it anyhow follows from the set edge reconstruction conjecture but I could not find anything about for what values that has been checked.