# Regular graph such that $2$ distinct vertices have same neighborhood set

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

If $G=(V,E)$ is a simple, undirected graph and $v\in V$, we set $N(v) = \{w\in V:\{v,w\}\in E\}$.

Is there an integer $k>1$ and a connected $k$-[regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph) graph $G=(V,E)$ such that there are $v\neq w \in V$ with $N(v) = N(w)$?

(Note that the definition of $N(\cdot)$ implies that $v,w$ cannot be adjacent.)

Comment: There are tons of obvious examples: every balanced complete multipartite graph, etc. Heck, even a $4$-cycle. Definitely not research level.

Comment: The $4$-cycle is nice because it is the only cycle that has a pair of vertices sharing the neighbourhood.  The number of graphs without any pair of vertices sharing the neighbourhood (apparently called mating graphs) is https://oeis.org/A004110.  Enumerative results using modern methods can be found in https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0042, it may be interesting to refine this to regular graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example with $k = 4$ is the octahedron.

Comment: This has the additional property that for *every* $v$ there is a $w$ such that $N(v) =  N(w)$. If we just want one pair $(v, w)$ with the property we can easily just make countless such graphs by first drawing $v, w$, their neighbors and the edges from $v$ and $w$ to said neighbors and then keep adding vertices and edges until the result is regular again

Comment: Why the downvote? I thought everybody loves Platonic solids?